# State retrieved from react-draft-wysiwyg is always one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm trying to implement something like a **Mobile Preview** section where after the user do their things in the editor, the changes that they've made will be shown in the **Preview** section concurrently.

The issue that I'm facing now is the method that I'm using in `Bulletin.js` to retrieve the html content from the editor seems to be 1 step behind (as in I need to do some actions like clicking anywhere or  to retrieve the last action made in the editor).

I want to make it so that the change is instant and not one step behind so that when user do things like changing font colour etc, it will be reflected to the preview section instantly.

**Bulletin.js**

```
const getContent = (htmlContentProp) => {
    setHtmlContent(draftToHtml(htmlContentProp));
};

<RichTextEditor getContent={getContent} htmlContent={htmlContent} />
```

**RichTextEditor.js**

```
const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    getContent(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
};
```

[image: Edit unruffled-ptolemy-8m2cr]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state); // this is asynchronous
    // so this will most likely be old value
    getContent(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
};
```

You have 2 easy options to work around this

- One is to not use hook here at all, you can consume your "state" directly

```
const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    getContent(convertToRaw(state.getCurrentContent()));
};
```

- Other option is to use `useEffect` which is more "correct" option if you for some reason need the hooks here

```
const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state); // this is asynchronous
};

useEffect(() => { 
    getContent(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
}, [editorState]); // this effect will trigger once the editorState actually changes value
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation and answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When this line `getContent(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))` runs in the `handleEditorChange` function, the `editorState` is not yet updated with the latest value. Since React state updates are [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

You can either use the `state` parameter in the `handleEditorChange` to get the latest data like below

```
const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
  setEditorState(state);
  getContent(convertToRaw(state.getCurrentContent()));
};
```

or use a `useEffect` to update state in parent based on changes in the child state.